# Juju bootstrap fails with dns resolution issues

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I am building a proof of concept install using old hardware and the AutoPilot install which is using Liberty.  I finally managed to get the physical servers to commission in MAAS and commenced the openstack-install.  I get the servers to deployed but then it fails, time and time again, on "Could not resolve host: streams.canonical.com\ntools"  I have used the localhost, private ip of the maas host, public address of the maas host and nothing works.  I set up all the avilable dns hosts in the maas network setup, maas host, nothing works.

OS is Ubuntu server 15.10, MAAS is V2.0, Openstack is Liberty (I think as it is not yet installed), hardware is a Dell 2900 Tower, 2 * quad cores and 32 Gb ram.
Any guidance would be highly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might probably be running into DNS issues.

Refer the following link:

https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-openstack/issues/235

https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/openstack-installer/issues/883